# Correct use of Option in scala?

Tags: beginner, scala

I'm somewhat new to Scala and am not sure if I'm doing things in a very Scala-esque way.

In particular, I'm not sure if I'm using `Option` correctly, since by calling `.isDefined`, I'm basically just doing ye olde Java null check. Also, the `getMethodAndAnnotationFromInfaces` method could probably be done better.

Please point out ways in which I could better leverage language features in the below code:

```
for (val method <- clazz.getMethods) {
        val methodAndAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(annotationType) match {
            case annotation: MessageHandler => Some((method, annotation))
            case _ => getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfaces(clazz.getInterfaces, method, annotationType)
        }

        if (methodAndAnnotation.isDefined){
            // do something
        }
    }
```

`getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfaces` function:

```
def getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfaces(interfaces: Array[java.lang.Class[_]], method: Method, annotationType: Class[_ <: java.lang.annotation.Annotation])
    : Option[(Method, java.lang.annotation.Annotation)] = {

    @tailrec
    def getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfacesInner(interfaces: Array[java.lang.Class[_]], acc: Option[(Method, java.lang.annotation.Annotation)])
        : Option[(Method, java.lang.annotation.Annotation)] = {
        interfaces.length match {
            case 0 => acc
            case _ =>
                try {
                    interfaces.head.getMethod(method.getName, method.getParameterTypes: _*) match {
                        case newMethod: Method =>
                            val newAnnotation = newMethod.getAnnotation(annotationType)
                            if (newAnnotation != null && acc.isDefined) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("The annotation is applied to the method in more than one interface of the class.")
                            }
                            getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfacesInner(interfaces.tail, Some((newMethod, newAnnotation)))
                        case _ => getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfacesInner(interfaces.tail, acc)
                    }
                } catch {
                    case e: NoSuchMethodException => getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfacesInner(interfaces.tail, acc)
                }
        }
    }

    getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfacesInner(interfaces, None)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write it like this:

```
for (val method <- clazz.getMethods) {
  val methodAndAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(annotationType) match {
    case annotation: MessageHandler => Some((method, annotation))
    case _                          => getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfaces(clazz.getInterfaces, method, annotationType)
  }

  methodAndAnnotation match {
    case Some((method, annotation)) => // do something
    case None => //whatever is relevant
  }
}
```

Or shorter:

```
for (val method <- clazz.getMethods) {
  method.getAnnotation(annotationType) match {
    case annotation: MessageHandler =>  // do something with method and annotation
    case _                          => {
      val v = getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfaces(clazz.getInterfaces, method, annotationType)
      //whatever is relevant
    }
  }
}
```

But it depends on what you want to do / if you have something to do when `getMethodAndAnnotationFromInterfaces` returns `None`.

Comment: Noooooooo! Not matching!

Comment: @Daniel - Why not matching?  I'm a newbie.  Odersky's book teaches handing Options with matching.

Comment: @EdStaub I have to kind of retract that. Matching will give you the most speed in a type-safe way. It's verbose, though, and can get you in the bad habit of matching everything, which leads to less composable code.

Comment: Good. It was not that bad ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For a "scalaesque way" to deal with `Option`, study [Tony Morris' Option Cheat Sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/). Additionally you can use for comprehensions as well (if you don't want to do anything in case of `None`):

```
for (value <- optionValue) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another improvent is to use Scala Reflection wihch comes in 2.10:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.Mirror
val c = Mirror.classToType(classOf[X])
val members = c.parents map { _.members filter (_.isMethod) }
val ann = Mirror.classToSymbol(classOf[Ann])
val meths = members map { _ filter (_ hasAnnotation ann) }
```

The output is not perfect yet, but the code is short, clear Scala and prints the expected result:

```
meths: List[List[scala.reflect.runtime.Mirror.Symbol]] = List(List(), List(method c, method a), List())
```

I tested this with following code:

```
// Java
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Ann {}

// Scala
trait T {
  @Ann
  def a: Int
  def b(i: Int): String
  @Ann
  def c(s: String): String
}
class X extends T {
  def a: Int = 5
  def b(i: Int) = i.toString
  def c(s: String) = "("+s+")"
}
```